# Calculator - C++ operator-overloading

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, overloading, calculator

I am new to object-oriented concepts. The following is my attempt at creating a basic calculator using class and operator overloading concepts. Please review it for improvements. Also, how do I make it more intuitive? I want to display: `+`,`-`,`*`,`/` as options and use `switch` on them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class calculator
{
    private:
        float val;

    public:
        calculator(): val(0)
        {}

        void getdata()
        {           
            cout << "enter number: ";
            cin >> val;
        }

        void showdata()
        {
            cout << "value: " << val << endl;
        }

        calculator operator + (calculator) const;
        calculator operator - (calculator) const;
        calculator operator * (calculator) const;
        calculator operator / (calculator) const;
};

calculator calculator::operator + (calculator arg2) const
{
    calculator temp;
    temp.val = val + arg2.val;
    return temp;
}

calculator calculator::operator - (calculator arg2) const
{
    calculator temp;
    temp.val = val - arg2.val;
    return temp;
}

calculator calculator::operator * (calculator arg2) const
{
    calculator temp;
    temp.val = val * arg2.val;
    return temp;
}

calculator calculator::operator / (calculator arg2) const
{
    calculator temp;
    temp.val = val / arg2.val;
    return temp;
}

void main()
{
    calculator obj1, obj2, obj3;
    char ch;
    int choice;

    obj1.getdata();
    cout << "1st value entered: ";
    obj1.showdata();
    cout << endl;

    obj2.getdata();
    cout << "2nd value entered: ";
    obj2.showdata();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input choice as integer: 1: +,   2: -,   3: *,   4:/     ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            obj3 = obj1 + obj2;
            break;
        case 2:
            obj3 = obj1 - obj2;
            break;
        case 3:
            obj3 = obj1 * obj2;
            break;
        case 4:
            obj3 = obj1 / obj2;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice! " << endl;
    }

    cout << "Result ";
    obj3.showdata();
    cout << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also overload `operator>>` instead of using `getdata()`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, calculator& obj)
{
    return in >> obj.val;
}
```

Similar approach with `showdata()`, using `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, calculator const& obj)
{
    return out << "value: " << obj.val;
}
```

As for your existing overloads, you shouldn't need to return a `calculator`.  You appear to treat each `calculator` object as a single value.  This makes each one to appear to be single-use, and the more values you wish to enter, the more objects thus the more code you'll need to have.

What you should do is maintain one object and have `val` maintained as you enter data.  However, this will also mean that your arithmetic operators aren't needed.  If you wish to keep them, then you'll have to approach this differently.  For instance, you can calculate (not merely input) a final value for different `calculator`s and use those operators to get a new value.  This may look like a needless approach for a simple calculator, but at least you're still able to utilize these arithmetic operators.

Some miscellaneous notes:

- [Be aware of the issues of using `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- You don't appear to be using `<conio.h>`, so just remove it.
- You don't need to use `std::endl` in so many places.  A simple `"\n"` for outputting a newline should be sufficient.  More info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).

Comment: thanks for the suggestions and additional operator overloading tips. That was very helpful. Could you please look into the switch case problem that I mentioned? I need it to be more intuitive.

Comment: @learner: For a `switch`, it already looks pretty intuitive.  The main problem with it now is that it doesn't really stop the user from inputting an invalid `choice` (the result will be displayed anyway).  You may need a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick review:

> ```
> #include <conio.h>
> ```

File not found.  But it seems that this include isn't required, so you can make your code portable by removing this line.

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

Don't do that - use the namespace properly.

> ```
>         float val;
> ```

We normally use `double` unless there's a compelling reason to use a larger or smaller floating-point type.

> ```
> void main()
> ```

The main function must return `int`.

> ```
>     char ch;
> ```

This variable is never used.

> ```
>             cin >> val;
> ```

This needs some validation that the input could be parsed as a number.  If the `>>` fails, we have uninitialised value in `val`, making all subsequent calculation meaningless.

> ```
>             cout << "Invalid choice! " << endl;
> ```

Errors should go to `std::cerr`.  There's no need to flush the output stream, so we can use a plain newline (`\n`) instead of `std::endl`.

---

### Design review

This looks like you have just learnt about object-oriented design, and are trying to apply it as an exercise.  That's fine, but it's not really a natural fit here.

The naming is a bit weird, and doesn't match with real-world expectations.  When I'm using a calculator, I don't get another calculator when I perform an addition - I have the same calculator, but with an update number stored in it.  You might find that the assignment operators (`+=` and friends) are a closer match to a real-world calculator.